# Fill Combobox only once dynamicaly at actionlistner

Tags: java-me, lwuit

In my project i want to first view country in combobox then selecting country state should be viewed then city based on state This is done in my project but the problem is that when i am aagain clicking on country then the state corresponding to that country is appended to combobox.. this should not be done the combobox should be refreshed then state should be added I am doing this in J2Me in lwuit can any one help me ??? if any one please help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you would explain how you are using combo boxes...

I'm guessing you are using addItem to add lots of items (which is bad) without removing the items.
To replace the existing items just do:

```
 combo.setModel(new DefaultListModel(arrayWithNewData));
```